# I spilled some .1M Copper Sulfate on my sweater

Tags: aqueous-solution

I have accidentally spilled some .1M solution of Copper Sulfate (CuSO4) on my white cotton sweater. It left a light blue stain and I’m wondering how I might successfully remove the stain from the sweater. Any help would be useful. My immediate thought is bleach, and since the sweater is white, it wouldn’t do anything to the color; but I don’t know for sure if that will work.

Comment: Water will do. Bleach won't.

Comment: You could also try a weak acid, such as vinegar. Rinse,repeat. Bleach is alkaline, and might cause a precipitate.

Comment: The sweater took a long shower and the Copper Sulfate stain is gone. Did take bloody long though. Thank y’all for your help.